# Is there a constant $c$ that $\frac{c}{1+x}$ be a probability density function for $x>0$?

Tags: probability, density-function

There are two conditions for probability density function: $f(x)\geq0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=1$.

Here for the first condition we must have $c\geq 0$. for the second condition:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{c}{1+x}=1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{c} = lim_{t\to \infty} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{1+x} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{c}=lim_{t \to \infty} (ln\vert1+t\vert - ln\vert1+0\vert) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{c}=\infty$$

so $c$ must be zero or there are no such $c$?

Comment: You are right. The function is not integrable for any $c>0$ so it is not a pdf.

Comment: You did the calculation right. And yes. There is no constant $c$.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$? Is it $0<x<\infty$?

Comment: @callculus42 $f(x)$ for $x\leq 0$  is zero.

Comment: @Lucy The integral $\int_0^{\infty }\frac{c}{1+x} \ dx$ does not converge. So it seems ill-defined. The integral of the pdf $f_X(x)=\frac{c}{(1+x)^2}_{0<x<\infty}$ does converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such $c$. You can't even take $c=0$, because then the PDF is $0$ everywhere, so the integral is $0$, not $1$.